# php search function

Tags: php

I am attempting to create a search function for user profiles on my site.

```
$search= $_POST['search'];
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".TBL_USERS." WHERE username LIKE '$search%'");
```

This is the code I use. This will only work if you search something that matches the start of the result. Is there any way I can return values that have what i type as part of the username regardingless of upper or lower cases?

Thankyou

Comment: Oh dear. SQL Injection vulnerability. Go and read http://bobby-tables.com/ immediately.

Comment: MySQL is already case insensitive by default.  You have to create a table with special collation options to make comparisons case sensitive.

Comment: If you search "luke" or "Luke", you should still get the same result

Comment: I know about SQL injection, i'll seperate it all out. That's old code. Already case insensitive thanks. Any ideas about the search from any part of user?

Comment: `'%$search%'`, see below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"%" is the wildcard, so if you also place it in front of your search string (like `%$search%`) it will match $search anywhere in username.

Use "LOWER" in SQL to make your username lowercase and "strtolower" in PHP to do the same, then execute the query to get case-insensitive results.

And as David Dorward said: read bobby-tables.com before you do anything else!!!

Comment: Thankyou, I understand SQL injection, thats an old piece of code. I shouldn't have put it up! Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should really add some sort of data cleansing, you should never take raw post/get data and insert it directly into a query.

With that said:

```
$search= strtolower($_POST['search']);
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".TBL_USERS." WHERE LOWER(username) LIKE '$search%'");
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using LIKE you can use the % wildcard on both sides of the input, this will return any users where $search is part of the username.

You may also want to look at [MySQLs REGEXP function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)

```
$search= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".TBL_USERS." WHERE username LIKE '%" . $search . "%'");
```

Answer (score -3):

You need to read about the terms "SQL Injection" and "PHP Prepared Statements" - Google for them... This is FAR more important that the question you have asked.

But since you ask, try the comparison all in upper case...

Martin.

Comment: Thankyou for the response, I know about SQ

Comment: I love StackOverflow - I answer the question, I point our a far more important point, and I get downvoted for it. I don't suppose whoever downvoted me would care to explain? I genuinely don't see what I have done wrong here...